# DocuSign_eSign::ApiError: Bad Request

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the Docusign Ruby SDK to make calls on the API. I have my code working when pointed to the developer docusign, when pointed to prod I'm getting the DocuSign_eSign::ApiError: Bad Request error.

I have already gotten my integration key/client id approved in production and I've also already done the authorization grant part, where you allow the integration key to send envelopes on a user's behalf. This has been done in dev and production.

```rb
desc 'Perform API call to list envelopes'
  task list: :initialize do
    options = DocuSign_eSign::ListStatusChangesOptions.new
    options.from_date = (Date.today - 10).strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
    options.status = 'completed'
    @list_results = @envelopes_api.list_status_changes @account_id, options
  end

  desc 'Build list results hash'
  task build_list_hash: :list do
    @list_results_hash = []
    @list_results.envelopes.each do |list_hash|
      @list_results_hash << { envelope_id: list_hash.envelope_id, status: 'pending', archive_at: Time.now + (86400 *30) }
    end
    puts "List results hash:\n #{@list_results_hash}"
    File.open(ENV['MASTER_LIST_FILE'], 'w') { |file| file.write(@list_results_hash.to_yaml) }
  end
```

I expect the output to be a list of envelopes which is what happens when running on demo.docusign

Update: Thanks for showing me how to get logs. It seems the error is with GetUserProfileImage

````
GET https://na3-app.docusign.net:8832/restapi/v2.1/accounts/91608b5d-d418-4c45-89f0-cd088504f99d/users/63757e15-8365-4fb9-9e7d-d9a8309f8e94/profile/image

TraceToken: 996d3b3f-2857-47d6-9d75-26a75b6b0a37
Timestamp: 2019-10-17T20:58:32.0932823Z

Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json;text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzipdeflatebr
Accept-Language: en-USen; q=0.5
Authorization: Bearer [omitted]
Host: na3-app.docusign.net
Referer: https://app.docusign.com/preferences/security
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0(Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0)Gecko/20100101Firefox/69.0
x-docusign-clienttransactionid: fa4e1202-09a4-431b-9abf-fe4d00acf565
x-csrf-token: c34f42c5aad288063afc8a6615be03c9
x-forwarded-for: 170.140.186.226, 162.248.185.11
x-docusign-authentication: {"IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
x-docusign-prettyprint: false
content-transfer-encoding: base64
x-forwarded-for-martini: 170.140.186.226
x-docusign-diagnostics: {"storedProcedureEventLogThreshold":"300"}
x-docusign-timetrack: CONN_START,2019-10-17T20:58:31.946Z;;REQ_SENT,2019-10-17T20:58:31.950Z;REST0_Start,2019-10-17T20:58:32.0620315Z
x-docusign-correlationtoken: fa4e1202-09a4-431b-9abf-fe4d00acf565
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384


404 NotFound
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 95
X-DocuSign-ClientTransactionId: fa4e1202-09a4-431b-9abf-fe4d00acf565
X-DocuSign-TimeTrack: CONN_START,2019-10-17T20:58:31.946Z;;REQ_SENT,2019-10-17T20:58:31.950Z;;REST0_Start,2019-10-17T20:58:32.0620315Z;REST0_End,2019-10-17T20:58:32.0932823Z
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 996d3b3f-2857-47d6-9d75-26a75b6b0a37

{"errorCode":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The URL provided does not resolve to a resource."}```
````

Comment: Can you capture an API log (https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) that shows the actual URL your application is hitting, as well as the full text of the error in the response?

Comment: are you making the call to get profile image? this is likely a red herring. This is probably the web app making the call and you don't have a profile image. Do you not see anything else in the logs?

Comment: what version of the Ruby Gem are you using?

Comment: Yes it was a red herring, my dev which is working also has the same 'error'. Nothing else in the logs really standout out to me. I plan on downloading working logs from dev and doing a diff to prod. My Gemfile.lock has ```docusign_esign (1.0.2)
      json (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.0)
      jwt (~> 1.0, >= 1.5.2)
      typhoeus (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1```

Comment: Looking again at the logs, the only thing that seems different is the 'brands' call
Dev:
```200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
X-DocuSign-ClientTransactionId: 26429694-b69c-4c00-83b0-941d5fe88f0b
X-DocuSign-TimeTrack: CONN_START,2019-10-18T00:51:50.056Z;;REQ_SENT,2019-10-18T00:51:50.062Z;;REST0_Start,2019-10-18T00:51:50.3263819Z;REST0_End,2019-10-18T00:51:50.3732615Z
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 3fce1cbe-8512-4e58-83ac-3d0a99189543

{}```

Comment: Prod:
```200 OK
[...removed for space]
X-DocuSign-ClientTransactionId: 46ccd89d-5c8a-4007-8ece-2696bcec178d
X-DocuSign-TimeTrack: CONN_START,2019-10-18T00:41:13.804Z;;REQ_SENT,2019-10-18T00:41:13.808Z;;REST0_Start,2019-10-18T00:41:13.7668183Z;REST0_End,2019-10-18T00:41:13.8137240Z
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: b9ada164-976a-4508-9320-3e68a4264669

{"senderBrandIdDefault":"f37e5184-1cbc-4339-a793-0e54cdd62569","brands":[{"brandId":"f37e5184-1cbc-4339-a793-0e54cdd62569","brandName":"Sending_1556120467256","isOverridingCompanyName":false,"isSendingDefault":true,"isSigningDefault":false}]}```

Comment: In Dev it continues after the Brand call to the list status codes call while in prod it stops at brand.

Edit: There's also some differences with a ConsumerDisclosure call that prod makes that dev does not. Honestly I don't know if these are just standard differences between a dev account and a prod account that's 21 CFR Part 11 compliant.

Edit #2 I just updated to the docusign gem version 3.0 and there is no change in behavior, dev still works prod still give same error.

Comment: this is not resolved, right? you are getting a 404 when you call to production? is that still the case here?